# Service Now API specify fields in CSV

Tags: servicenow

I am trying to get a list of incidents from Service Now which is active. I just need a specific field called due_date from the data. If I use JSON

```
curl -s -L --user username:password --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type:application/json" "https://myservicenow.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_query=opened_atRELATIVEGE@dayofweek@ago@100"
```

I get a URL like

```
    {
        "active": "true",
        ......
        "due_date": "2015-07-22 07:07:28",

    }
```

I want to do the same thing using CSV web service. So I used

```
curl -s -L --user username:password "https://myservicenow.com/incident.do?CSV&sysparm_query=opened_atRELATIVEGE@dayofweek@ago@100"
```

I get fields like

```
"number","sys_created_by","caller_id","short_description","subcategory","u_subcategory_detail","category","priority","state","assignment_group","assigned_to","opened_at","resolved_at"
```

But the field due_date is not present. How can I specify the fields to retrieve in CSV format ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSV unloader is dumping fields based on a [UI View](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=View_Management) for the table in question. The fields that are present on the UI View are the ones that get included in your output. Since you have not explicitly specified a view, the "Default view" is used, just like if you were to load a list within the application without a `sysparm_view` URL parameter specified.

Here's what you can do:

- Go to the instance and open the list for the table (e.g. /incident_list.do)
- Modify your view via Personalize/Configure List to add the `due_date` column

  - Don't use the Cog-wheel list personalization, that won't actually change the view
- Try your CSV pull again, you should have the due_date column included!

Now, if you don't actually want to change your default view, you can create a new UI View on the target table (give it a name like 'csv_dump'), and then add the parameter `sysparm_view=csv_dump` to your URL, thusly:

```
curl -s -L --user username:password "https://myservicenow.com/incident.do?CSV&sysparm_view=csv_dump&sysparm_query=opened_atRELATIVEGE@dayofweek@ago@100"
```

...passing the value for sysparm_view as whatever name you used to create your UI View.

Comment: Where, exactly is the Personalize menu?  I'm at /wm_order_list.do and can't find anything that says Personalize except the cog wheel.